# Expected length of longest arithmetic sequence

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions

Given a natural number $n$, we define the vector valued random variable $\vec Y_n := (X_1, \ldots X_n)$ where all $X_i$ are independently uniformely distributed on $S_n := \{1, \ldots, n\}$.

Further we define the function $f: S_n^n \to \mathbb N$ where $f( \vec s )$  denotes the length of the longest subsequence of $(s_i)_{i=1}^n$ that forms an arithmetic progression.

Is it somehow possible to say *anything* (e.g. calculate the expected value) about the distribution of $f(\vec Y_n)$ or even calculate the distribution?

I have no idea how to work with the condition of the *arithmetic subsequence*.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your exact question as stated, but in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.12339.pdf) it is proven that if $\vec{Y}_n$ is a random *permutation* of the first $n$ integers, then the expected length of its longest subsequence is roughly $\log n/\log\log n$.  My suspicion is that one could use nearly identical ideas from that paper to show that the same thing holds for your variant of the problem.